# foreachPartition method of RDD is not working in GCP cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to upload data in spark job through API calls where API has payload limit of 5MB per API call(3rd party API limitation). I am accumulating data to form API body until payload limit to minimize the number of API calls. I am doing the same inside foreachPartition method of RDD with some comments to analyze. But this entire code is running totally fine when I run spark job locally in my machine (APIs are getting called & data is getting uploaded) but not working the same way in GCP cluster. While running the job in GCP dataproc cluster data is not getting uploaded through APIs so I believe the code inside foreachPartition is not getting called.

While running locally I can see all the log messages(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) but While running the job in GCP cluster I can see only few log messages(1,3)

Sample code is below for your reference

Would appreciate your suggestions to make it running in GCP cluster as well.

```
def exportData(
    client: ApiClient,
    batchSize: Int,
  ): Unit = {
    val exportableDataRdd = getDataToUpload() //this is rdd of type RDD[UserDataObj]
    logger.info(s"1. exportableDataRdd count:${exportableDataRdd.count}") //not a good practice to call count here but calling just for debugging

    exportableDataRdd.foreachPartition { iterator =>
      logger.info(s"2. perPartition iteration")
      perPartitionMethod(client, iterator, batchSize)
    }
    
    logger.info(s"3. Data export completed")
  }

def perPartitionMethod(
    client: ApiClient,
    iterator: Iterator[UserDataObj],
    batchSize: Int
  ): Unit = {
    logger.info(s"4. Inside perPartition")
    iterator.grouped(batchSize).foreach { userDataGroup =>
      val payLoadLimit = 5000000 //5 MB
      val groupSize = userDataGroup.size
      var counter = 0
      var batchedUsersData = Seq[UserDataObj]()
      userDataGroup.map{ user =>
        counter = counter + 1
        val curUsersDataSet = batchedUsersData :+ user
        val body = Map[String, Any]("data" -> curUsersDataSet.map(_.toMap))
        val apiPayload = Serialization.write(body)
        val size = apiPayload.getBytes().length
        if (size > payLoadLimit) {
          val usersToUpload = batchedUsersData
          logger.info(s"5. API called with batch size: ${usersToUpload.size}")
          uploadDataThroughAPI(usersToUpload, client) //method to upload data through API
          batchedUsersData = Seq[UserDataObj](user)
        } else {
          batchedUsersData = batchedUsersData :+ user
        }

        //upload left out data
        if(counter == groupSize && batchedUsersData.size > 0){
          uploadDataThroughAPI(batchedUsersData, client)
          logger.info(s"6. API called with batch size: ${batchedUsersData.size}")
        }
      }
    }
    logger.info(s"7. perPartition completed")
  }
```

Comment: Can you please put the output of the exportableDataRdd.count in case of running on cluster? Also, can you log exportableDataRdd.getNumPartitions?

Comment: exportableDataRdd.count is 25000
exportableDataRdd.getNumPartitions : 4

Currently for testing purpose I am keeping exportableDataRdd.count to 25000 (limiting to 25k records in my query before while creating RDD) in my code but it can go to few millions.

Comment: If there are 4 partitions, then I don't understand why log message(2) won't be logged. Are you sure there are 4 partitions in both cases when you run locally vs on cluster?

Comment: Yes, I see 4 partitions in both cases in Master & Local run but see log(2) only in local